# Overlay plot on an image inside a for loop Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, overlay

I am trying to overlay a matplotlib plot on an image using the following code snippet.

```
plt.imshow(image, zorder=0)
plt.plot(some_array, zorder=1)
plt.savefig('image_array.png')
```

If I now include this code inside a `for` loop to overlay a plot on a different image in each loop, the resulting images overlap. For example, `image_array2.png` sits on top of `image_array1.png` and so on.  How do I correctly save the figures without overlapping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
for i in range(number_of_images):
    plt.imshow(image[i], zorder=0)
    plt.plot(some_array[i], zorder=1)
    plt.savefig('image_array' + str(i) + '.png')
    plt.clf()
```

If you're trying to save multiple plots on different images using a for loop, the plots end up overlapping. But don't worry, there's a way to fix it. You can add a line of code, called 'plt.clf()', before creating the next plot. This line of code clears the current figure, so the next plot you create doesn't overlap with the previous one.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, number_of_images)
for i in range(number_of_images):
    ax[i].imshow(image[i], zorder=0)
    ax[i].plot(some_array[i], zorder=1)
plt.savefig('image_array.png')
```

You can also use matplot subplot method.

Comment: Many thanks!  plt.clf() resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `plt.clf()` after `plt.savefig()` to clear the current figure before the next iteration of the loop.
This will ensure that the previous figure is cleared before the next one is plotted, preventing overlaps. Alternatively, you could also create a new figure at the beginning of each iteration using the `plt.figure()`, which would also clear any previous figures:

```py
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(image, zorder=0)
plt.plot(some_array, zorder=1)
plt.savefig('image_array.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# load image
img = plt.imread("image.jpg")

# loop through your data
for i in range(5):
    x = np.random.rand(10)
    y = np.random.rand(10)

    # create a new figure
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.axis('off')
    # plot the data on top of the image
    plt.plot(x, y, 'o-', color='r')
    plt.title('Plot {}'.format(i))
    plt.show()
```